# Configuring Cruise Control Net with sourcesafe - Unable to load array item 'executable'

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, nant, visual-sourcesafe

I'm trying to create a continuous integration environment. To do so, I've used a guide that can be found at http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040621.htm.
In this step by step, the goal is to create a CI with CCNet, NAnt, NUni, NDoc, FxCop and source safe.
I've been able to create my build by using the command prompt (despite the the different versions issues). The problem has come with the configuration of ccnet.config
I've made some changes because of the new versions, but I'm still getting errors when starting the CCNet server.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue or point where to find a guide with this scenario?

The error that I'm getting: 
Unable to instantiate CruiseControl projects from configuration document.
Configuration document is likely missing Xml nodes required for properly populating CruiseControl configuration.
Unable to load array item 'executable' - Cannot convert from type System.String to ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.ITask for object with value: "\DevTools\nant\bin\NAnt.exe"
Xml: E:\DevTools\nant\bin\NAnt.exe

My CCNet config file below:

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="BuildingSolution">
    <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet</webURL>
    <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>
    <triggers>
        <intervaltrigger name="continuous" seconds="60" />
    </triggers>
    <sourcecontrol type="vss" autoGetSource="true">
      <ssdir>E:\VSS\</ssdir>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe\SS.EXE</executable>
      <project>$/CCNet/slnCCNet.root/slnCCNet</project>
      <username>Albert</username>
      <password></password>
    </sourcecontrol>
    <prebuild type="nant">
      <executable>E:\DevTools\nant\bin\NAnt.exe</executable>
      <buildFile>E:\Builds\buildingsolution\WebForm.build</buildFile>
      <logger>NAnt.Core.XmlLogger</logger>
      <buildTimeoutSeconds>300</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    </prebuild>
    <tasks>
      <nant>
        <executable>E:\DevTools\nant\bin\nant.exe</executable>
        <nologo>true</nologo>
        <buildFile>E:\Builds\buildingsolution\WebForm.build</buildFile>
        <logger>NAnt.Core.XmlLogger</logger>
        <targetList>
          <target>build</target>
        </targetList>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>6000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
      </nant>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
      <merge>
        <files>
          <file>E:\Builds\buildingsolution\latest\*-results.xml</file>
        </files>
      </merge>
      <xmllogger />
    </publishers>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only a first guess but configuration in `<prebuild>` element might be broken. Try this:

```
<prebuild>
  <nant>
    <executable>E:\DevTools\nant\bin\NAnt.exe</executable>
    <buildFile>E:\Builds\buildingsolution\WebForm.build</buildFile>
    <logger>NAnt.Core.XmlLogger</logger>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>300</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </nant>
</prebuild>
```

Just like the `<tasks>` block the `<prebuild>` block is a collection of task elements. In Your case this is a single `<nant>` task.

Currently I don't have access to CCNET documentation since the ThoughtWorks server is down - once again. So I'm not able to verify my advice at the moment.

BTW: Did You know that You don't have to start the server in order to verify Your configuration. Check the configuration with `CCValidator.exe` from `[installdir]\server` prior to starting CCNET server.